# Error: libjvm.so failed to load: j9vm29 in Docker Desktop Mac M3 Sonoma 14.3

Tags: java, docker-compose, java-17, macos-sonoma, eclipse-temurin

I am getting errors after upgrading to macOS Sonoma 14.3 in docker container. Container image is build on top of `eclipse-temurin:17.0.8.1_1-jdk-jammy`.

- Device: Macbook M3 Pro
- OS version: Sonoma 14.3
- Docker Desktop Version: v4.26.1

```
2024-01-23 15:40:38 libjvm.so preloadLibrary(/opt/java/openjdk/lib/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so): /opt/java/openjdk/lib/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument
2024-01-23 15:40:38 libjvm.so failed to load: j9vm29
```

Building images and running container in docker.

Answer (score 1):

From this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77880846/19797701

If you have Rosetta enabled in Docker Desktop, try disabling it (should be under "General" in Docker Desktop settings).

Answer (score 0):

With MacOS Sonoma 14.4 (23E214) update, this JDK issue is fixed.

Comment: It's always best practice to give a reference or official blog to justify the answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).