# db2start: error while loading shared libraries: libicudatadb2.so.32: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument

Tags: docker, db2, arm, virtual-machine, apple-m1

I got this error when i tried to run db2 on a docker container. Anyway, I'm using apple silicon chip. It worked perfectly just fine before my laptop got updated to from sonoma 14.2 to 14.3. Now I got this error when I want to run the container.

```
DB2 State : Operable
DB2 has not been started
Starting DB2...

db2start: error while loading shared libraries: libicudatadb2.so.32: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: RSA DSA ECDSA ED25519 
(*) All databases are now active. 
(*) Setup has completed.
HOSTNAME: 54f62d87e0cf
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, config/install, sqlfLogUpdateCfgParam, probe:30
CHANGE  : CFG DBM: "Dftdbpath" From: ""  To: "/database/data" 

2024-01-24-06.05.46.957009+000 I5190E318             LEVEL: Event
PID     : 70332                TID : 140737382190592 PROC : db2flacc
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: 54f62d87e0cf
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, config/install, sqlfLogUpdateCfgParam, probe:30
CHANGE  : CFG DBM: "Federated" From: "0"  To: "1" 
(*) Ending DB2 with db2stop force and db2ts "stop for text"
db2stop: error while loading shared libraries: libicudatadb2.so.32: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument
(*) Done
```

This is my run command.

```
docker run --rm -ti --platform linux/amd64 -itd --name db2 --privileged=true -p 50000:50000 -e LICENSE=accept -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=root -v db2-volume:/database ibmcom/db2 uname -m x86_64
```

Hope someone can help with my problem.

Comment: Check this https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2start-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libicudatadb2so32-cannot-enable-executable-stack-shared-object-requires-permission-denied

Comment: @fadhil Have you had any luck resolving this? I realized that the linux/ppc64le docker image works fine on Sonoma 14.3 but our DB Backups can't be imported since it's running on an OS with different Endian configuration.

Comment: @D.McDermott so far still have not resolved this unfortunately. Using linux/ppc64le may got very poor performance.

Answer (score 2):

Turning of Rosetta in the Docker Desktop settings resolves the issue. To properly use Rosetta we have to wait for an fix by either apple or docker itself.

[image]

Obviously this impacts DB performance, but for our local development this is ok.

Comment: Thank you @D.McDermott. While we wait for their fix this might be the best solution to fix db2start and db2stop problem temporarily compared to using ppc64le arch which is so badly slow.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't figured out the issue was related to this new feature that's been added within `Rosetta` setting.

I solved in my own build installing and using `execstack`, through which I cleared the executable stack flag of the impacted shared library.

There should be a way to set it for `DB2` as well, I don't know how, but likely you have to build your own `Dockerfile` while starting from `ibmcom/db2` image, and the command you could issue with `RUN` operation is the following:

```
execstack -c /PATH/TO/LIBRARY/libicudatadb2.so.32
```

`execstack` could be installed via any package manager in the `Dockerfile`, if it isn't already included in the distribution you're building through `docker`.

Here there're other references related to this problem:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49039/chcon-fails-to-fix-cannot-enable-executable-stack-as-shared-object-requires-er
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40983824/2996437
- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/916#issuecomment-365898305
- https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/cannot-enable-executable-stack-as-shared-object-requires-invalid-argument-error/40041